# Can I recover a PowerPoint file that was replaced with a blank presentation?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-powerpoint, file-recovery, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

A colleague had her PowerPoint presentation overwritten with blank presentation, using PowerPoint 2007 on Windows 7.

System Restore is turned off and it looks like Shadow Copy also didn't work as there is no previous version of this file. Auto Recovery is turned on, but I can't find anything under the folder. I've also tried to use a recovery tool (Active@ File Recovery), but it couldn't find any backup.

1. How could this happen? When browsing around, I noticed a lot of similar issues. Is this something common?
2. How can we prevent or minimize this risk?
3. Is there anything else we can try to recover this file?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cannot offer a way to recover the file. However, you can enable Previous Versions by going to Control Panel > System > System protection > Configure > Select preferences > OK.

Then create a previous version.